# Xorg log spams Present-flip: queue async flip during flip on CRTC 0 failed: Invalid argument

Tags: xorg, logs

What does this error mean which I find in in my `Xorg.0.log`

```
(WW) modeset(0): Present-flip: queue async flip during flip on CRTC 0 failed: Invalid argument
(WW) modeset(0): Present-flip: detected too frequent flip errors, disabling logs until frequency is reduced
```

I'm seeing this repeated many times, with occasional screen flashing/blanking.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a bug upstream

- https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/-/merge_requests/658/diffs?commit_id=1a1bd5cf7a1a3364afb625f020e1c013fbabfbb6

I'm not sure what the solution is here. I'll probably re-evaluate Wayland.